# Wrong URLs generated by Websphere Portal JSF 2 Myfaces Portlet Bridge

Tags: jsf-2, websphere-portal, resource-loading

I tried to integrate JSF 2 (standard Myfaces 2 implementation from IBM Websphere 8) and Primefaces 4 in a Websphere Portal 8 Portlet.

Primefaces was loaded but the Primefaces resources were not loaded. So I opened my firebug and took a look at the ressource URL. Something like this is generated:

```
url("/.Myapp/javax.faces.resource/editor/images/buttons.gif.faces.faces?ln=primefaces&v=4.0") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

After deleting the second **.faces** in firebug the resource was loaded. So there must be a problem with the resource URL generation. Why is the  suffix from web.xml added twice to the url? How to prevent Websphere Portal 8, the Portal Bridge or what ever is generating this wrong url from doing it?

Any ideas?

Robyn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to configure my web.xml as shown below and it worked:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <async-supported>false</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Faces Servlet with *.jsf url pattern was required as part of JSF v1.2. Now In JSF v2.0 *.html is required.

Regards,
Narayan